# Finding the original (x,y) coordinates after zooming

Tags: java, javafx

I am using the below code for zooming effect, this code will be applied to a group consisting of a map image which allows the user to click on a city to get information about it, but the problem is when the user zooms I need to know the original (x,y) coordinates in order to display the proper information. How can I solve this problem? what I have tried is to get the zoom ratio and then multiple (zoom out) or divide (zoom in) new coordinate by it.

```
 private Parent createZoomPane(final Group group) {
        final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
        final StackPane zoomPane = new StackPane();

        zoomPane.getChildren().add(group);
        zoomPane.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
          @Override public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
            event.consume();

            if (event.getDeltaY() == 0) {
              return;
            }

            double scaleFactor =
              (event.getDeltaY() > 0)
                ? SCALE_DELTA
                : 1/SCALE_DELTA;

            group.setScaleX(group.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
            group.setScaleY(group.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);
          }
        });

        return zoomPane;
      }




root.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        // root is the map parent.
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            double x = mouseEvent.getX();
            double y = mouseEvent.getY();
            // Then I use x,y to find the city which the user wants, but when i apply zoom
            // effect the x,y changes fron the orignal values.

        }
    });
```

Comment: Which problem? `MouseEvent`s for the scaled node use it's untransformed coordinates...

Comment: @fabisn I am not sure what you mean if you could explain further that would be great.

Comment: `MouseEvent.getX` and `MouseEvent.getY` always use coordinates in the local coordinate system of the node where the event handler is added (without transformations such as scale applied to them)...

Comment: @fabian I have updated my question to further explain my problem, and MouseEvent.getX and MouseEvent.getY do change after the zoom effect

Comment: No idea what `root` is, but registering a listener at the scaled group or at a descendant of the group (in case you need local coordinates for that node) should work.